# Create 2D grid in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to create  a grid in Matlab, I want mark some cell as free , some(blacks) as obstacle, and mark one cell as start and another cell as end point and some as path, like below image,how can I achieve this in Matlab?

[image]

Comment: You do realize that you are asking for people to do free work for you right?

Comment: [What have you attempted so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @StivenLlupa work for free? people here to help each other, if you want money go another place,here is community to help each other developres

Comment: There seem to be a few different questions here. 
  How do you create a random number of blocks such that their total area is a given number `obstacleNo`?
  How do you randomly distribute such blocks in a given `columnNo` by `rowNo` area so they don't intersect?
  What are the conditions such that you can even do that?

Comment: @Steve first I want to know how to create m*n grid on matlab,

Comment: @StivenLlupa ok, I update my question, answer if you you can or need money?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get you started, here's how to create something that looks like the image you included using [pcolor](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcolor.html).

```
A = ones(11,11)
A(5,1:3) = 0;
A(8:10,2:3) = 0;
A(5:7,6:7) = 0;
A(1:3,8:10) = 0;
pcolor(A)
colormap(gray(2))
% To flip the vertical axes, uncomment next line
%axis ij
```

[image: pcolor example image]

For start and goal

```
patch([1,2,2,1],[2,2,3,3],[0.5 0.5 1]) % [r g b] values
text(1.25,2.5,'Start')
patch([10,11,11,10],[10,10,11,11],'g')
text(10.25,10.5,'Goal')
```

Comment: so tell me how can I put 2 sign in this grid, I want mark a cell as start, and one as end , how can I do that?

Comment: Not sure, try [annotation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html) or [text](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html)

Comment: I think if colorized cell and put text in it is will be enough.
I mean  use as example color start cell as aqua then write in there start, and color end point as green and write there (text) End.

Comment: [patch](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html) and [text](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) should work then.

Comment: I update my question with better image of what I want, please help me to implement it. tnx

Comment: @zhilevan There you go, you should be able to figure the rest out

Comment: I findout how, thankyou very much, I hand it with map